# Method call with C# dynamic in inherited type

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have noticed an unexpected behavior while trying to extend a base class. Here is a sample for this problem:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new CoolProgram();
        test.Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        var arr = new object[]
        {
            1, // int
            1L, // long
            "Hello World" // string
        };

        foreach (var dyn in arr.Cast<dynamic>())
        {
            DoSomething(dyn);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int:" + i);
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Str:" + str);
    }
}
```

The `Program` defines two methods `DoSomething` which are overloaded by `int` and `string` arguments. The `Start` method creates an array of object`which contains boxed values. After the definition, the elements will be iterated with casted`dynamic`. This works fine so far (without the long value).

If I create an additional inherited class `CoolProgram` and add another method to the type for `long` the program will throw an `RuntimeBinderException` and tells me that the best overload was `DoSomething(int)`. The method of `CoolProgram` was not executed.

```
public class CoolProgram : Program
{
    protected override void DoSomething(int i)
    {
        // This works
        Console.WriteLine("Cool Int: " + i);
    }

    protected override void DoSomething(string str)
    {
        // This works
        Console.WriteLine("Cool Str: " + str);
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(long i)
    {
        // This is a new method for long
        Console.WriteLine("Long:" + i);
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain this behavior or have a solution for it?

Comment: `dynamic` just defers type resolution and subsequent compilation steps to runtime. So what you're really asking is why overload resolution does what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example can be simplified further:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program test = new CoolProgram();
    dynamic i = 1L;

    test.DoSomething(i);
    //test.Start();
}
```

The issue is that as far as the `Start()` method is concerned, `this` has the type `Program`. Adding a `virtual` overload for `DoSomething()` means nothing in the context of the `Start()` method.

Likewise in my simplified example above. The compile-time type of `test` is `Program`, just as the type of `this` in `Start()` is `Program`. Thus, the `DoSomething(long)` overload is not visible in that context, and can't be called.

If you want it to be visible, you need to either add it to the base class, or make sure that the reference used to call `DoSomething()` is statically typed as `CoolProgram`. Note that since the method is declared as `protected` in `CoolProgram`, you'd also have to change the accessibility, if you want to go the route of changing the static type of the reference to `CoolProgram`.

Finally, if you really want fully dynamic type resolution here, you can:

```
private void Start()
{
    dynamic this2 = this;

    var arr = new object[]
    {
    1, // int
    1L, // long
    "Hello World" // string
    };

    foreach (var dyn in arr.Cast<dynamic>())
    {
        this2.DoSomething(dyn);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The above would of course require that `DoSomething(long)` be made `public`, as I noted above.

Comment: I corrected the typos. Thank you! Now I understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

1)first issue is access modifier protected due to which you are not able to access the overloaded method with Long type as a parameter. i changed it to internal now it is accessible.

2) The second issue is you are creating child class CoolProgram object but you are calling parent class DoSomething method you should use  test.DoSomething(dyn); and make the child class object global to access it in your Start method.

```
public class Program
{
static CoolProgram test;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test = new CoolProgram();
    test.Start();
}

private void Start()
{
    var arr = new object[]
    {
        1, // int
        1L, // long
        "Hello World" // string
    };
    //test.DoSomething(21474836470);
    foreach (var dyn in arr.Cast<dynamic>())
    {
        test.DoSomething(dyn);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

protected virtual void DoSomething(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Int:" + i);
}

protected virtual void DoSomething(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Str:" + str);
}
}
// from here child class
public class CoolProgram : Program
{
  protected override void DoSomething(int i)
  {
    // This works
    Console.WriteLine("Cool Int: " + i);
    base.DoSomething(i);
 }

 protected override void DoSomething(string str)
 {
    // This works
    Console.WriteLine("Cool Str: " + str);
 }

 internal virtual void DoSomething(long i)
 {
    // This is a new method for long
    Console.WriteLine("Long Int:" + i);
 }

 }
```